# activity_main cannot be resolved or not a field

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android and I was trying to make a simple application on android and this "activity_main" error is not getting cleared.I have gone through all the available answers

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.      
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ZouZou
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 (at)Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 (at)Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

}

Comment: @ZouZou please help me on this..

Comment: Is the layout and the menu XML available ?

Comment: @zamil nizar edit your question and add code in it.

Comment: Do you have an xml file named "activity_main" in the res/layout folder ?

Comment: you should post your code using the edit option under your question

Comment: @Oli there is no file called menu.xml in there but only main.xml in res-->menu

Comment: @ZouZou yes i have that file also...

Comment: @ZouZou please help me on this problem.I have tried all the methods I have got from this website

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Clean project then try to run it. I faced the same problem. You can also do this:

Remove from your code following imports `import android.R;` or `import your.application.packagename.R;`

Now clean the project and run it.

Comment: I have tried this...but no use..sorry..
Is there anything else I should do???
I have also tried the ctrl+shift+O then also the same problem after clean

Comment: @zamilnizar did u clean after u did this ?

Comment: @zamilnizar then there must be some error in ur xml layout files.

Comment: @Zamilnizar check your xml file. is there any error or not.?? or post here your xml file code.

Comment: @Segi there is no error in my xml file.I am getting the correct interface in my main.xml's GRAPHICAL LAYOUT

Comment: @Segi did that too as u mentioned earlier in the comment.But still no changes :-(

Comment: Removing `import android.R` worked for me. Still I don't know why did this happen and why this worked after removal of `import android.R`
Could anybody clarify this?

Comment: followed everything .. still does not work (having red line beneath activity_main !!

Answer (score 17):

Let me explain(put more detail) what exactly is happening with the above code.

FYI, there are two types of `R.java` file exists:

1. one is your project's `R.java` file, which you would use to access resources/layout of your project.
2. second is Android's `R.java` file which contains ID/index of the native resources like anim, color and many more resources, which you can access by using `android.R.color.black` way.

### Mistake:

Now, you are making mistake by importing `android.R` which is not allowing you to access `main_activity.xml` of your project.

### Solution:

Remove `android.R` and import R file of your project. You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> simply, will display available options.

Comment: sir nice explanation as always expected from you. +1 for you

Comment: @PareshMayani yes..that was the problem..
I have tried import com.example.my projectname.R and it worked...!!!!
yohooooo...

Comment: I am having same issue. but, when i press Ctrl+Shift+O it imports `android.R` namespace instead of my package resource. I have also tried to find out R namespace in my package resource but, couldn't find R namespace of my package. There is no error in my xml layout. Is there any other way to import my package resource namespace manually?

Comment: Replacing Android.R with com.{my_project}.R and cleaning the project afterwards didn't help. I had to restart the eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Irfan What what! Are you still using Eclipse, why not Android studio? Sorry for talking about a different point than issue but you should really migrate to it quickly!

Comment: @Paresh Mayani, I am new to Android and the video I was watching started off with the Eclipse. But I have moved on to Android Studio since then and yes, development in AS is such a breeze.

Answer (score 3):

U seem to have imported wrong R.java class

- problem is in the first line "import android.R"
- use your applications R.java class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the activity_main.xml file spelled correctly.  I experienced the same problem due to having a misspelled file name.